# Expression engine login issue (membership module)

Tags: authentication, membership, expressionengine

I am using Expression Engine 2. I wanted to create a simple members only section. I've created the relevant permissions using membership groups and I have implemented rights to certain pages for the membership groups.

I have used the login form tag (http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/member/index.html) to create my login form. However when I log in, it just does nothing. I believe it was working before as the site was tested, signed off and in use a few months ago, but now the login form does not seem to work at all. It just submits back to the page without logging in. If I login via admin, it all works, so it is only the login form on the website!

The code in my EE page template is as follows:

```
{if logged_out}
{exp:member:login_form return="site/index"} 
  <label>Username:</label> 
  <input type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="32" /> 
  <label>Password:</label> 
  <input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="32" /> 
  {if auto_login}
    <p><input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' name='auto_login' value='1'  /> Remember me</p>
  {/if}
  <p><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" /><br />
  <a href="{path='member/forgot_password'}">Forgot your password?</a></p>
{/exp:member:login_form}
{if:else}
  <p>Logged in: {username}<br />
  <a href="{path='LOGOUT'}">Log out</a></p>
{/if}
```

I'm grateful for any help as to what to check, or any tips to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: Difficult one, as it may be down to your member group settings or an extension you have activated.

You're setting it to return to "site" template group and the "index" template You could try just using a normal URL for the return with a forward slash at the start (e.g. "/sign-in"). Try disabling extensions and see if that makes a difference...? Try logging into the form with your super admin details, if still a problem, it's not going to be settings in EE, it'll be either a redirect issue or an extension that's grabbing the login hook.

Comment: You say it 'just submits back to the page' - do you see the EE 'You have now logged in' redirection message beforehand? Or does it literally just reload the page and display the login form again? If you have any other forms on the site (e.g. contact forms) are they still working?

Answer (score 2):

It could be the difference between viewing the site with/without the www prefix.

eg:
www.mysite.com = logged out
http://mysite.com = logged in

Check the site url in general preferences.